# Creating Polygon in Angular 2 using agm library

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, typescript, polygon

I am trying to create a polygon using angular 2 [AGM](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/) library. The template is attached below:

```
<div id="google_map" [@cardtable2]>
            <sebm-google-map #maps [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [scrollwheel]="false" [zoom]="zoom">

                <sebm-google-map-marker 
                    *ngFor="let m of markers; let i = index"
                    (markerClick)="clickedMarker(m.label, i)"
                    [latitude]="m.lat"
                    [longitude]="m.lng"
                    [label]="m.label"
                    [markerDraggable]="true"
                    (dragEnd)="markerDragEnd(m, $event)">

                    <sebm-google-map-info-window>
                    <strong>{{m.label}}</strong>
                    </sebm-google-map-info-window>          
                </sebm-google-map-marker>
            </sebm-google-map>
        </div>
```

And in the controller i attach polygon as below:

```
var city_bounds = [ 
        {
            "longitude" : 77.088103,
            "latitude" : 11.066228
        }, 
        {
            "longitude" : 77.027745,
            "latitude" : 11.113179
        }, 
        {
            "longitude" : 76.937558,
            "latitude" : 11.100018
        }, 
        {
            "longitude" : 76.867772,
            "latitude" : 11.082932
        }, 
        {
            "longitude" : 76.867772,
            "latitude" : 11.038643
        }, 
        {
            "longitude" : 76.899553,
            "latitude" : 10.968071
        }, 
        {
            "longitude" : 76.925336,
            "latitude" : 10.924184
        }, 
        {
            "longitude" : 76.984468,
            "latitude" : 10.92891
        }, 
        {
            "longitude" : 77.032123,
            "latitude" : 10.971053
        }, 
        {
            "longitude" : 77.066364,
            "latitude" : 11.000079
        }, 
        {
            "longitude" : 77.065678,
            "latitude" : 11.030235
        }
    ]


this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
  this.path = city_bounds.map(point => {
    return new google.maps.LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude);
  });

  let city_bounds_polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    // map: this.mapsElementRef._elem.nativeElement,
    paths: this.path,
    editable: false,
    draggable: false
  })

  city_bounds_polygon.setMap(this.mapsElementRef);
});
```

The above code is just a small snippet of large component file, where `this.mapsElementRef` is reference to sebm-google-maps which i got using @ViewChild("maps") decorator. When i start the node server i get the error as below

```
app/map.component.ts(233,34): error TS2345: Argument of type 'ElementRef' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Map'.
  Property 'fitBounds' is missing in type 'ElementRef'.
```

I know there is something wrong with map reference, in plain javascript, reference of the maps is available since we create maps using `new google.maps.Maps` as seen [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map) . However here map is created using angular directive `sebm-google-map`. So, i got the reference of it using `ViewChild` and used it with `setMap`, and i got the error above .

I guess i have to use `AgmPolygon` from the Agm library as [here](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/directives/AgmPolygon.html), but i have no idea how to use it, since in docs i don't find any example. Can anyone provide right pointer on how to use the Agm library to create Polygon?

The version of agm is `0.16.0` , actually it's the libary with old package name `angular2-google-maps/core`

Answer (score 0):

I solvent whit agm +2:

```
 mapClicked(data){

    this.path.push({ lat: data.coords.lat, lng: data.coords.lng });

    let newArray = Array<any>();
    this.path.forEach((item) => {
      newArray.push(item);
    });

    this.path = newArray;

   }
```

// end mapClicked